# Did grammar behaviour break between 6.c and 6.d?

Tags: raku

I have a grammar that ws working fine in 6.c (2018.01) - I cannot get it to  give stable output in 6.d (2019.03.01).

When I turn on Grammar::Tracer (nice!), the pattern seems to be consistent.

But with same input 'm/s', my output wanders randomly through a range of results for *example*...
* m/s=m.True
* m/s=True.m
* m/s=s-1.True
* m/s=m.s-1 (this is the one I want, don't care about the order)

I am suspicious of the unam => ｢s｣ ｢/｣ ｢m｣ content of the match object (see debug code) -- the Tracer shows only one match for unam in each branch.

All advice welcome!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

sub get-dime( $dime-str ) { 
        use Grammar::Tracer;

        my $unit-names = '|m|s';

        grammar UnitGrammar {
            token TOP     { <dim> <divi> <den> }
            token divi    { \/ }
            token dim     { <unam> }
            token den     { <unam> }
            token unam    { <$unit-names> }
        }    
        class UnitActions {
            method TOP($/)     { make $/.values.[0].made~'.'~$/.values.[1].made }
            method dim($/)     { make ~$<unam> }
            method den($/)     { make ~$<unam>~'-1' }
            method divi($/)    { make True }
        }    

        my $match = UnitGrammar.parse($dime-str, :actions(UnitActions));

        #[[ verbose for debug (also uncomment #use Grammar::Tracer)
        say "$match=", $match.made;
        say "--------------------";
        say $match.values;
        say $match.values.[0].made;
        say $match.values.[1].made;
        #]]  

        return $match.made if $match.so;
}
say $*PERL.compiler.version;
say get-dime( 'm/s' );
```

ban
[image]

Comment: Please provide minimal *runnable* code. What is `$unit-names`? There is `token unam    { <$unit-names> }` but `$unit-names` is not defined

Comment: Well that sucks. I'm confident we'll figure it out if you provide reproducible code but I'd like to emphasize *minimal* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). So please consider experimenting in removing most of the code you've posted as well as adding in what's missing to come up with a *minimal* reproducible example that works in 6.c but not in 6.d. (And maybe include a `say $*PERL.compiler.version` so we know for sure which version yo u're using.) TIA.

Comment: When you write "with same input 'm/s', my output wanders through a range of results" do you mean **A** repeatedly passing the same input, but in a loop or similar, in one program, and each time you run that one program you get the exact same sequence of wandering results, or **B** repeatedly running the same program, with just that one input each time, and, after rebooting your computer, over a sequence of runs you get the exact same sequence of wandering results, or **C** a program, with either one, or repeated inputs, and you get apparently *random* results each run and over multiple runs?

Comment: Hi @HåkonHægland - thanks you for the steer on code - this is now edited to be a runnable program. I have reduced the unit-names from about 200 to about 20 and still experience the same problem.

Comment: Hi @raiph - I have also golfed down to about a par 5. This is minimal as I think I can get it without changing the nature of the error or the problem. One weird thing is that I no longer call divi in the make, but if I remove that line the error is quite different.

Comment: @raiph - I have rebooted and still experience the same issue. I mean C <random>

Comment: PS unit-names now down to 2. FWIW I tried without a leading | to see if that fixes it - with no joy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Håkon named the game. You teed off to land on the courseway. I got us near the green but in the rough. @ugexe spotted the ball. @Håkon skipped this hole, moved to the next tee and holed in one. So I guess I'm left to write the post-game wrap up.

---

It's not `6.c` vs `6.d`.

The underlying issue is that hashes are specified to have their key/value pairs listed in random order. In earlier compilers the hash list implementation returned key/value pairs in a fixed order. Then [samcv implemented hash randomization for MoarVM last year](https://cry.nu/perl6/secure-hashing-for-moarvm/). It breaks code that incorrectly relies on hash order.

So the following code -- on Rakudo/MoarVM since 2018.05 -- randomly displays either `(a b)` or `(b a)`:

```
say .values given { apple => 'a', bananas => 'b' }
```

Your code was calling `.values` on a `Match` object.

Calling that method will usually boil down to something similar in effect to:

```
say .values given ( apple => 'a', bananas => 'b', 0, 1, 2 ) .Capture
```

which will display a list starting with `0 1 2` (they're positionals, so they display first, in their correct order) followed by either `a b` or `b a` (they're named so they display last, in random order).

This in turn is because a `Match` is a sub-class of [`Capture`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Capture) and inherits its `.values` method from that class. As [its doc](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Capture#method_values) says:

> Returns a `Seq` containing all positional values followed by all named argument values.

In your code there were no positional captures. So all you got to see was the values of named captures. But of course they're in a list, so appear under indices `.[0]`, `.[1]`, etc. which presumably tricked you into thinking they were ordered (in combination with the fact that, in earlier Rakudos, their supposedly random order was in reality fixed).

`.caps` improves on this because it orders its values according to their match positions in the input. This will ensure stable ordering of a list of the values of named captures -- provided none of the captures share a matching position:

```
say .caps given 'foo' ~~ / $<alias>=<ident> /
```

will randomly display either `(alias => ｢foo｣ ident => ｢foo｣)` or `(ident => ｢foo｣ alias => ｢foo｣)`.

## My first answer

For the record, here was the first version of this answer:

Here it is golf'd about as far down as I think it can go:

```
grammar {
  token TOP { <one> <two> }
  token one { 1 }
  token two { 2 }
}.parse('12').values.say;
```

In the v2018.04 that's the current version running on tio.run this reliably displays `(｢1｣ ｢2｣)`. In the v2018.12 that's the current version running on glot.io this produces either of `(｢1｣ ｢2｣)` or `(｢2｣ ｢1｣)`, randomly varying between the two.

I don't know if this is a bug. Investigation continues but I thought I'd post this as an initial answer.

Comment: Looks like hash randomization to me

Comment: I don’t care about the order. But I don’t understand where the ‘True’ values are coming from... or how to avoid them.

Comment: The `True` values come from you writing `make True` and then `say`ing them randomly. For example `say $match.values.[0].made;` will randomly catch either the `True` you made or one of the other sibling makes you made. Every place you've written `.values` you injected randomness. In the earlier compiler the randomness was faked, so each time `.values` was called it returned things in the same ("random") order. The `.[0]` was always the same. In the later compilers it's truly random.

Comment: Thank you @raiph - I am ok with the randomness all (good way to avoid relying on setup specific state when testing) - I just couldn't see the wood for the trees - don't need that 'make True' after all! (don't know why I put it there in the first place)

Comment: .oO ( I love forests but on a golf course trees on the fairway aren't fair ) Yw. I'm glad we quickly collectively figured it out. :)

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what order [`$/.values`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match#(Capture)_method_values) is supposed to return (I get the randomized order as you describe), but instead of using `$/.values`:

```
method TOP($/)     {
     make $<divi> ?? $/.values.[0].made~'.'~$/.values.[1].made
                  !! $/.values.[0].made
}
```

you can use try [`$/.caps`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match#method_caps):

```
method TOP($/)     {
    make $<divi> ?? $/.caps.[0].value.made~'.'~$/.caps.[2].value.made
                 !! $/.caps.[0].value.made
}
```

at least this works for me.

Comment: Thanks håkon this looks cool and I guess i need to reread the make docs now i have a bit more of a clue about p6 in general. Do you know why this routine is called ‘caps’ b any chance?